# Aframe FPS adjustment using tick handler

Tags: aframe, frame-rate

A newbie here. I am trying to adjust the FPS from default 60, 72 90 to 30 using the tick handler. After spending some substantial time trying to understand game loops, FPS and in this case the tick handler i still cannot grasp on how to achieve this. This is the code i have been fiddling with but no joy.

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('FPS-30', {
  init: function () {

    this.tick = AFRAME.utils.throttleTick(this.tick, 33, this);
  },

  tick: function (t, dt) {}
});
```

and

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('FPS-30', {
tick: utils.throttleTick(function(t, dt){}, 33);
});
```

As documented in [here](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/utils.html#aframe-utils-throttletick-function-t-dt-minimuminterval-optionalcontext), and also [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2136). I have attached the component to the **a-scene** element and also **a-entity** but no success so far! Can someone shine some light on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot lock FPS to a specific value. A-Frame render loop fires at a rate defined by `requestAnimationFrame` (usually 60) in 2D mode and the native refresh rate of the available headset in VR mode (60, 72, 90...). Not advised for applications to interfere because there are time sensitive operations like frame submission, re-projections or sensor readings that might not work as expected if not properly synced.

You can though control the rate that a component `tick` method fires via [throttleTick](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/utils.html#aframe-utils-throttletick-function-t-dt-minimuminterval-optionalcontext). Below an example of it working. Notice console messages printing the time elapsed between tick calls in ms:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/congruous-weak-thumb?path=index.html%3A12%3A10